# In a private blockchain network, can we delete the first N blocks and reassign the N+1th block as the genesis block?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, private-blockchain, storage, blocks

I am aware of the data loss caused by deleting the first N blocks. But I am curious to know whether such a task is possible or not. If so, how to practically implement it?

( I am using go-ethereum. If it is not possible in go-ethereum, I would like to know whether it is possible in other blockchain-based projects like bitcoin. )